# GPS signal combiner

Tags: rf, antenna, radio, gps, split

I want to use WP4N+ as a GPS signal combiner with NEO 6M receiver. Here is my schematic.

[image]

On power on, resistor 22 Ω is getting VERY VERY HOT and I do not receive any signal from the satellites. Without the WP4N+, with a single antenna, the GPS module works fine.

I calculated 50 Ω impedance trace width and other parameters, trace parameters are correct.

**GPS_VCC_RF** goes to PIN8 according official NEO-6M schematics.

[Here is the WP4N+ datasheet.](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/WP4N+.pdf)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "a GPS signal splitter" - what are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I want to use 4 antennas instead of 1.

Comment: @Alatriste A) multiple antennas on one receiver port will never do anything useful for GNSS. B) even for the more typical use (one antenna, N receivers) you need to bypass the bias power around the splitter (and only get it from one port so that they don't fight).

Comment: Strange IC. I'd at least expect to see a typical application as part of the datasheet. The complete lack of capacitors is particularly fishy. I don't know what this one is supposed to do, but shouldn't you rather use a RF switch which the RFIC can use to select one of several antennas using an "antenna diversity" feature?

Comment: @Lundin I think it's just some sort of passive component

Comment: Also what about band pass filters.

Comment: It is a power splitter/combiner.  It is essentially nothing but a bunch of coils and transmission lines.  I expect that "SUM" is a DC short circuit to ground through an inductor.

Comment: So you are telling me to use RF switch instead of this IC?  @Lundin

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using 4 antennas instead of one?

Comment: @Alatriste Only if the part supports antenna diversity, of which I have no clue. It seems like they also recommend some external LNA, and optionally a SAW bandpass. All of it usually comes with a bunch of DC blocking caps in series.

Comment: I have a box with the GPS module inside, I thought maybe it's better to use 4 antennas(around the box)  for BETTER connectivity/visibility. @Finbarr

Comment: Just hooking up 4 antenna to one receiver will not work. Instead you could get 4 antenna and 4 receivers and then check for which one has a lock on position and ignore the ones that do not.

Comment: Maybe just use PATCH ANTENNA ARRAY and "cover" it around my module for better satellite visibility?

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify that the desire is to combine signals.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to combine signals from multiple antennas, will not work properly in the general case due to lack of a clearly defined phase centre.  The only way for this to work reliably is with a single well defined patch antenna with controlled phasing between elements to act as a single antenna

For the more common use as a splitter, the antenna needs to be connected to the SUM port, and the receiving devices (such as the NEO 6m) to the antenna ports.

You then need to think about the DC antenna power which is supplied via R? and L?.

Typically GPS splitters either have:

- one "DC pass" port, and the other ports "DC blocking"
- all ports "DC blocking" and separate power injection.

In the first case, the splitter needs to be designed to tolerate the DC bias from the receiver on the power port, and have AC coupling on the other ports.

Given that many GPS receivers have open antenna detection circuits, you may also need dummy load resistors.

In the latter case, you need dummy loads on all ports, AC coupling on the antenna to splitter, and DC power injection via an inductor.

I suspect you splitter has a DC path to ground (via one or more inductors), and this is overloading the DC feed via R? and L?.

To get a splitter to work I suggest you:

- add AC coupling caps on all the WP4N+ ports
- move the antenna to the SUM port, and the receiver to one of the splitter ports
- keep your antenna feed on the antenna side of the cap on the sum port
- consider if you need dummy loads on the split ports.

(You don't provide a link the the NEO module, but it may already have a receiver power circuit.  If so, you can just drop R? & L?, and connect the splitter port with the NEO to the antenna SUM port via an inductor.  This is then the "DC Pass" port, and will allow the NEO on that port to power the antenna.)

Comment: Given that you say "GPS signal splitter", I assume you want to be able to use one antenna across multiple receivers? - NO , 4 antennas for ONE receiver

Comment: That is not going to be a good plan.  What "location" do you expect it to return, given that there isn't a single phase centre?

Comment: for example, if my module has one antenna and it's "looking" into the ground, then there will be no connections between satellite and my module, so I thought, if I add more antennas around my module, (each antenna on each side) then it will be more visible.

Comment: maybe just use patch antenna array?

Comment: Maybe just use PATCH ANTENNA ARRAY and "cover" it around my module for better satellite visibility?

Comment: If you look at the gain charts for GPS antenna, you will find almost all offer broadly hemispherical response, tapering off to a bit above the horizon (and most work better with a nice wide ground plane to help this).  The most accurate survey grade antenna also have extremely well defined "phase centers" for each of the frequency bands the support, specified relative to the mounting point, including orientation.

For best perf you want is a single antenna, with a good ground plane, pointing upwards.  Adding extra antenna and trying to combines them is counterproductive.

Comment: btw, the NEO is definitely a uBlox. I'm guessing NEO-6M based on the cut-off bit of the next letter, but it could be something newer. They provide a "VCC_RF" that can be used for antenna power, but it's up to the integrator to provide the bias tee circuit.